# Can't install Pipewire on ubuntu 20.04.4

Tags: 20.04, sound, bluetooth, pipewire

I am unable to use HSP/HFP profile in pulseaudio so i was trying to switch to pipewire but for some reason i am unable to install pipewire it says

E: Package 'pipewire' has no installation candidate

I have already added the ppa for pipewire and i have searched everywhere on internet but i can't find anyone else with the same problem.

Terminal image showing the error:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: In the future, please don't post a screenshot. Please copy and paste the code into your question and format it by highlighting the code and pressing CTRL+K. Alternatively, you can also format code in your question by using "code fencing" by placing ``` on the line above the block of code and ``` on the line below the block of code.

Answer (score 0):

Your error message states that "However, the following packages replace it".

**Install the packages listed in the error message.**

Additionally, you can search for available packages using the `apt-cache search` command:

```
apt-cache search pipewire
```

you can filter the results by using the `grep` command:

```
apt-cache search pipewire | grep -i "pipewire"
```